# The number of executions of the code (with limit of executions and coroutine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to create a simple spawner with some delay after spawn zombie. I set limit for zombie's count but that doesn't work because were created 12 zombies instead of 10. I can just fix it with replacing `lenght <= max` on `lenght <= max-2` but **I don't know what's the root of the problem**.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    GameObject zombie;
    bool condition;
    public int max;
    int lenght;
    void Start()
    {
        zombie = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Zombie") as GameObject;
        max = 10;
        condition = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GameObject[] zombies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Zombie");
        lenght = zombies.Length;
        Debug.Log(lenght);
        if (condition && lenght <= max)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Spawn());
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        condition = false;
        while(lenght <= max){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            Instantiate(zombie);
        }
        condition = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating multiple coroutines, don't you just want a single one that spawns zombies? The problem is likely that you are starting extra coroutines and causing a race condition. If multiple coroutines are running there are multiple threads accessing the variables at different times, this might mean one coroutine reads the value of `length` just before the loop updates it, meaning it will spawn a zombie even though length has just recently been updated to equal max.

Comment: To avoid this I made "while" and "if (condition && lenght <= max)". When I start first coroutine, "condition" is becoming false and "extra coroutines" aren't executing

Comment: There are no extra coroutines, you just need one and you should always create it. You should create one coroutine and it will wait 1 second and create a zombie each time, but you want to move your yield statement to come after you create the zombie, not before. The coroutine should check the value of condition and create a zombie if condition is true (I assume this is active/inactive flag?)

Comment: @Charleh okay, I will try it.

Comment: @Charleh Now "yield" come after creating a zombie but now creates 11 instead of 10. "Condition" was the flag which I used to start again coroutine if last coroutine executed (to not multiple coroutines). I moved StartCoroutine in void Start (with necessary changes) but it doesn't affected

Comment: @Charleh but Thank you for help (about  "yield"). I will make "<" instead of "<=" and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "root of the problem" is your IF statements, they both have a *less than or equal to* (=<) operator which means it'll stop once it reaches a number past 10 which spawns one extra zombie.
Using only a *less than* (<) makes sure it's stops if the number is 10 since 10 isn't less than 10.

Comment: Also I should move yield after creating a zombie(like Charleh wrote above).Thanks.